# parse_git_dirty:11: command not found: tail

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3

I was following this [tutorial](https://ashleynolan.co.uk/blog/launching-sublime-from-the-terminal) to try and be able to open Sublime text from terminal but I messed up along the way and now I keep getting this error in terminal:

```
parse_git_dirty:11: command not found: tail
```

I can't even seem to run this command:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

Which returns this:

```
zsh: command not found: open
parse_git_dirty:11: command not found: tail
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured out what I messed up.

In following the tutorial, I embarrassingly added

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)
```

including the ... and saved the file. I didn't realize it would mess everything up. I was able to figure out where bash_profile is saved and edit the file manually.